# How to write a regex to match end of string in Apache LocationMatch?

Tags: regex, apache

Using Apache LocationMatch, I'm planning on matching requests(mobiles.touch.json) and setting header values only for certain requests. However, the header is not. I'm not sure if the regex I'm using is correct for now. So I tried following Apache, but nothing worked. Do you have any suggestions ?

URLs
${domainname}:/abc/abc/abc/jp/mobiles.touch.json,
${domainname}:/xyz.net/ert/ert/ert/mobiles.touch.json,
${domainname}:/abc/def/def/as/mobiles.touch.json

Option1 
<LocationMatch "/mobiles.touch.json">
Option2 
<LocationMatch "/(mobiles.touch.json)">
Option3
<LocationMatch "/mobiles.touch.json$">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last one was almost correct. You have to escape the dots as `.` is
used to match any character.

```
<LocationMatch "/mobiles\.touch\.json$">
    Header always set X-My-Header "My-Value"
</LocationMatch>
```

Also check that `mod_headers` is enabled on the server. You can check
that by listing all the symbolic links in the "*mods-enabled*"
folder :

```bash
ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
```

You can either create the symbolic link yourself or use *Apache*'s
tool :

```bash
sudo a2enmod headers
```

Also be aware that `<LocationMatch>` can't be used in a `.htaccess`
file. It has to be put in the virtual host or server config file.

If you need it in the `.htaccess` then you can replace it by a
`RewriteRule` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /mobiles\.touch\.json$ - [ENV=MOBILES_TOUCH:true]
Header always set X-My-Header "My-Value" env=MOBILES_TOUCH
```

Comment: @ezhil Welcome! Was it the missing `mod_headers`? Or is it the `always` option that did the trick? Because, actually, your `"/mobiles.touch.json$"` should have worked also. The only problem with your 3rd pattern is that it would have matched "/something/mobiles-touch-json" or other variants, due to the `.` meaning "any char".

Comment: Thanks for your message. @patrick, actually I am adding "SubstituteMaxLineLength 7m" value inside LocationMarch. But it is not working. I checked that mod_headers is enabled. Do I need to check anything to add "SubstituteMaxLineLength"?

Comment: @ezhil : According to [*Apache*'s documentation about SubstituteMaxLineLength](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_substitute.html), it's part of the `mod_substitute` module, so you have to enable this one, not `mod_headers`. The documentation always says which module is delivering the functionality. But I'm not sure if I understand: You say you want to set some specific headers, but actually, the substitute module seems to be there to change the body response, not the headers. It might be good to explain what is your clear intention in the question. You want to change the JSON?

Comment: Thanks for your input. Yes, I want to some header and substitute value for the above header match. I checked both mod_headers & mod_substitute modules enabled in apache.